# python sqlalchemy dynamic order_by

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

how can I dynamically set the order by direction based on a variable, as in asc or desc for a sqlalchemy query for a sqlite db?

pseudo code as follows:

```
sort_order = "asc"

sql_session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(sort_order(ResultsDBHistory.postsize)).limit(max_items_shown)
```

if I try this it won't accept the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the `.asc()` or `.desc()` methods as attributes on `ResultsDBHistory.postsize`:

```
order = 'asc'
column_sorted = getattr(ResultsDBHistory.postsize, order)()
sql_session.query(ResultsDBHistory).order_by(column_sorted).limit(max_items_shown)
```

as columns have `asc` and `desc` methods.